# Can control particle emission from material’s texture?

Tags: particles

question is if I can emit particle from texture which assigned as material.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do it as using Texture toggle in Particle properties tab.
and assigned same texture with texture in Material.

Thank you for first answer, It is very efficient tip, I will use it too.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok so wrong answer, but I keep it for those who may be interested:

If you want, for a particle, to get the right color from an object that has an image texture on, you need to:

- Create your emitter material.

[image]

- Duplicate this material, assign it to your particle, enable the *Texture Coordinate's From Instancer* option.

[image]

- It should work:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  And sorry about my vague question,   I wanted to say if it’s possible to birth particle only at yellow color in your answer for example.

Comment: to emit particles only depending on the color of the texture? I don't know, you can emit from only a vertex groups but it doesn't answer your question I guess. Maybe edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: I will edit question in two hours.. sorry